# Truncate string c++ to length without cutting word

Tags: c++, string, split, cpu-word

I have as in input a C++ string and if the size of my string is greater than 64 character i need to cut it into smaller string (to be stored into vector of strings) but i need to be sure to not cut a word; so i need to split when i find spaces; i wrote a code but i am not sure it is the best way to tackle the problem.
Any help will be appreciated thanks; here the code that i wrote.

```
void Truncate_string(string& S; vector<string>& T){
     int index;
     while(S.size()>64 && !S.empty()){
         index=63; // The index where the cut would be made
         while(index>0 && S.at(index)!=' ') --index; 
         if(index==0) index=63; // no space found
         T.push_back(S.substring(0,index));
         S=S.substring(index);
     }
 }
```

Comment: What should happen if there are more than 64 consecutive non-space characters?

Comment: _"but i am not sure it is the best way to tackle the problem"_ Your code doesn't _tackle the problem_ at all.

Comment: -For the 64 consecutive non space characters that the purpose of if(index==0)
-I forgot to declare index it is an int
- πάντα ῥεῖ  can you explain me my mistake ?

Comment: You don't need `S.at(index)` since you've explicitly checked that `index` is in bounds. Just use `S[index]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many string manipulation issues, the answer is in the standard library. `std::string` already has a member function that will do this:

```
while (S.length() > 64) {
    std::string::size_type pos = S.rfind(' ', 63);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        break; // no 64-bit-or-less substring
    else {
        T.push_back(S.substr(0, pos));
        S.erase(0, pos);
    }
}
if (!S.empty())
    T.push_back(S);
```

This version is not smart about space characters; you probably should remove them when doing the push back. But that's a separate matter.

EDIT: this hasn't been carefully reviewed, so there may be off-by-one errors.

Comment: There is a case when it will be an infinit loop, we can have space at pos=0 (special after a truncate), it think a better solution is to cut at pos+1

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try:

Border cases like empty string or single word >64 must be captured

```
void trunc(const std::string& str, std::vector<std::string>& vec)
{
    std::string buf; 
    std::stringstream ss(str); 

    ss >> buf;
    vec.push_back(buf);

    while (ss >> buf)
    {        
        if(vec.back().length() + buf.length() < 64)            
            vec.back() += ' ' + buf;            
        else        
            vec.push_back(buf);

    }
}


 int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string text("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");

     trunc(text, vec);

     for(auto itr : vec)
     {
         std::cout << itr << std::endl;
     }
     return 1;

 }
```

Im sure there are better solutions with iterators

Comment: Thank you for the answer; but if the first word is longer than 64 it will be pushed in the vector no?